# Why does this method of modifying kernel memory work?

Tags: unix, kernel, cisco

I have no experience of kernel programming or anything low level. I just watched this video and at [21:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liW_u4vjdVs&t=1270s) the presenter started to talk about modifying kernel memory using two pointers.

From my understanding he simply points pointer A to some user memory t1 and B to some kernel memory t2, and after a syscall (which looks like `memset`) contents of t1 is copied to t2.

My question is: since this is mostly a concept demonstration, how does it work, and why the syscall does not check memory address? P.S. this is Cisco Unix 4.1.

Comment: "We discuss a set of 0-day kernel vulnerabilities in CNU..." We present the ... process which led to the discovery of the vulnerabilities described below. We also present methods of exploiting the following vulnerabilities remotely." -- that means nothing here is normal. These are demonstrations of bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the presenter mentioned it: It is/was a security bug. Obviously the kernel didn't refuse to copy data into kernel memory - there was no check implemented.